# What kind of backup software could protect my Openstack VMs?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I compare some mianstream backup solutions like vinchin,commvault,and so on.but until now I haven't decide which is suitable. I need two features:copy backups to offsite,agentless backup.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with vinchin backup&recovery which is a easy to use,reliable backup software to protect your openstack environment.Besides,we support agentless backup for VMs,that is to say you don't need install proxy in your each VM which is needed backing up,only install a small plug-in on your hypervisor layer.And copy backups to offsite is supported by vinchin backup&recovery version5.0 which will be released in August.I would like to invite you to test it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I'll take time to test vinchin backup&recovery,and I'm looking forward to vinchin version5.0.

Comment: Sorry there are another question I wanna ask. what kind of storage resouce type does vinchin support? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.feel free to contact me if you have any troubles during installation and test.here is email:  sales@vinchin.com

Comment: Vinchin supports  Partition,local disk,LVM,ISCSI,Fibre channel,NFS,CIFS    Hope my answer could heip you.